# Reduce message textbox size

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, sms

I have ICS on my Samsung Galaxy S2 using the stock messaging app. When unlocking the phone after getting a new message, I'm taken straight to the message itself. This is good. However, it seems to go straight to "reply-mode", in that the text box and keypad take up most of the screen and I can't actually read the message itself, maybe just the last 2 lines of it.

Is there anyway to not go straight to "reply-mode", just to "read the message mode"? Or at least reduce the size of the textbox back to 1 line like it was in Gingerbread?